# How do you prevent expanding outer element when adding padding?

Tags: css

I'm not a designer. When writing CSS it often happens that I need to add some padding to an element. How do you avoid that padding to propagate to the parent element ?

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
  <input id="login">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
  width: 300px;
}

#login {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

If you use that HTML+CSS, you'll see that the `#outer` element is bigger than `300px`. The easiest solution if to re-write the `#login`'s `width` to `"300px - to_pixel(1em)"`. It works well but also means that now the font size needs to be fixed. Is there another way where I don't need to convert everything in pixels ?

Comment: what have font size to do with padding? dont get it... anyway, width of element = width + padding + border + margin according to css box model http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: It's such a shame that support for CSS3 `calc()` is [so poor](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).  It would make this a breeze.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you want is the [box-sizing](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/) property. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/nVaE9/) for it in practice. Just add this:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to your `#login` CSS. This is supported in [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing), including IE8+.

Comment: I have no words for how awesome this neat tidbit is for me - thank you! (clearly there are a lot of clever people out there as I'm astounded you haven't been upvoted to like a thousand :))

Answer (score 4):

You can css `box-sizing` property like this:

```
#outer {
  width: 300px;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
}

#login {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/TQXdn/

*`box-sizing` does not work in IE7*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to fix this or adjust according to width + padding . The Actual Size when you are using padding will be

> actual size =  Defined Width +  Padding Width + Border Width

then if you want to limit it to the container size then take care about [the CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

```
#outer {
  width: 300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:1em;
}

#login {
  width: 100%;
}
```

It will put the input in center of the container.. `Use Box Model` as suggested in question comments also.

Answer (score -2):

There is my solution:

```
width : calc( 100% - 10px );
padding: 5px;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
#outer {
  width: 300px;
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
}

#login {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
}
```

See it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/22ABj/

Comment: Odd, mine's the best and most portable answer.  It doesn't require box-sizing, and yet no votes :(

Comment: You're relying on `absolute` positioning, which means that: a) you need to specify a height for the container and b) the input itself has no padding (rather the container has the _illusion_ of padding), which is presumably not the desired visual effect. If IE7 support is essential, some variation on @Niranjan's answer is the most practical.